# FPGA Multiplication and Division

Tags: fpga, math

**Background**

I am trying to estimate the speed of a quadrature encoder with the following equation

```
v = Δx/Δt
```

Δx is a 16 bit signed integer and Δt is a 16 bit unsigned integer. |Δx| is guarenteed to be <= Δt so that |v| <= 1.0. Both of these are sampled at a rate of 16MHz.

I desire the output to be in a signed Q8.9 (18 bit) fixed point format in units that differ from those that naturally occur. To achieve this I plan on implementing some form of the following arithmetic.

```
final_v = ((current_x - old_x) / (current_t - old_t)) * (2^9 * 160)
```

where the 2^9 promotes the fractional part of the division to Q8.9 format and 160 is the factor I need to get the desired units.

I am implementing this with verilog and Vivado 2016.2 on an Artix-35T FPGA and plan on using Xilinx's Divider Gererator and Multiplier IPs to do the multiplication and division for me and I would like to minimize latency as much as possible (throughput is not as important).

**The Question**

Would it be prefered to multiply by the constant (2^9 * 160) first and then divide or the other way around or is there a better algorithm I should be using? Are there common pitfalls that I should be aware of?

Comment: You are overthinking this, unless you have very specific requirements on how often you need to update the answer. With suitable choice of units, you can do this with little more than two counters. (Multiplication by 160 requires a single addition).

Comment: Much easier for an FPGA if you just count (bi-directional) the position change in a fixed amount of time. Are you really that concerned with actual units?

Comment: @Tut yes I am concerned with the units because I later multiply the speed with another value and use the resulting product to control a physical output value. I thought of using the constant Δt approach, but I want to have accurate values for relatively low frequencies, and I do not want to make Δt any longer than necessary as I want to minimize latency